# JS object sorting date sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS object defined as follows -

```
var item = {};
item[guid()] =
{
    symbol: $('#qteSymb').text(),
    note: $('#newnote').val(),
    date: $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', dt) + " " + dt.getHours() + ":" + minutes,
    pagename: getPageName()
};
```

At some point in my app I am getting a list of those (`Items`) back from chrome.storage and I would like to be able to sort it based on the `date`

Here is what I am doing

```
var sortable = [];

            $.each(Items, function (key, value) {
                if (value.symbol == $('#qteSymb').text() || all) {                        
                    sortable.push([key, value]);
                }
            });

            console.log(sortable);

            sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
                a = new Date(a[1].date);
                b = new Date(b[1].date);
                return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
            });

            console.log(sortable);
```

It doesn't seem to work. The first and second `console.log(sortable);` is the same. I have tried changing `return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;` to `return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;` just to see if I am getting any change to `sortable` but nothing happens...
Thank you~

Comment: I'd suggest just storing timestamp `dt.getTime()` as well and simply sort by it like: `return a[2] - b[2];`

Comment: Have you checked that you actually get the desiredDate objects from `new Date(a[1].date)`? -> use `console.log(a.toString()+' and '+b.toString())` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `console.log` show the same array because when you use `console.log(sortable)`, `sortable` is passed by reference, and console output happens AFTER finishing your script - when `sortable` has been already sorted.

Making your code simple:

```
var arr = [3,2,1];
console.log(arr); // Produces `[1,2,3]` because its printed
                  // to the console after `arr.sort();`
arr.sort();
console.log(arr); // Produces `[1,2,3]`, as expected
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfwph/

---

**Workaround**

If you want to be able to do `console.log` with an array to see it before being modifyed, you can use `.slice(0)` to *copy* the array, i.e. to obtain **another** array which contains the same elements as your array.

```
var arr = [3,2,1];
console.log(arr.slice(0)); // [3,2,1]
arr.sort();
console.log(arr); // [1,2,3]
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfwph/2/

Edit: better use `.slice(0)` instead of `.slice()`, which is supported on FF but ecma262 spec says only `end` argument is optional.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks Oriol. So that would mean console.log is not a reliable debugging tool? How would you confirm the sort? I put break points in both the `console.log(sortable)` spots but the array is still the same.

Comment: @americanslon If you want to debug arrays, it's better to *copy* them using `.slice()`

Answer (score 0):

@Oriol:

I just did an identical fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JaU4g/ , but for me it DID work!

```
var ar=[3,1,8,4,7,2,4,1]
console.log(ar.join(','));
ar.sort();
console.log(ar.join(','));
```

giving:

```
[18:55:31.616] "3,1,8,4,7,2,4,1"
[18:55:31.616] "1,1,2,3,4,4,7,8"
```

Comment: That's because you use `ar.join(',')`, so you convert `ar` to an string. Then, when you modify `ar`, the string isn't modified.

Comment: That is not right. `.join()` simply returns a string derived from an array object and leaves the actual array unchanged. Otherwise I would not be able to join it again a second time ...

Comment: Yes, I meant that but I didn't explain well. But I wanted to point that you call `console.log` with an string instead of the object `ar`. Then, if you change `ar`, the string won't change.

Comment: So, in order for @americanslon to see a difference he should actually generate an independent instance of the array by doing something like `var arr1=sortable.slice(0);`?