# Getting Compiled HTML from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting the compiled html of a page in AngularJS. Here's the code:

JS:

```
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('main', []);

        app.directive("compile", ['$compile', function ($compile) {
            return {
                link: function(scope, elem, attr){
                    var compiledHTML = $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
                    console.log(compiledHTML);
                    var returnString = '';
                    for(i=0; i<compiledHTML.length; i++)
                        returnString += compiledHTML[i].outerHTML;

                    console.log(returnString);
                }
            };
        }]);
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="main" compile>
    <body>
        {{3 + 4}}
    </body>
</html>
```

What is strange is in the first console.log(), it shows the compiled data, 7, in the outerHTML property, but when I output all the .outerHTML, it shows the uncompiled version, {{3 + 4}}

Comment: Maybe the problem with `console.log` is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/18597550/1529630

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was the opposite of that problem. The correct output only showed up after the page was done loading, but not for the returnString.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like it was a timing issue. Waiting to process the compiledHTML did the trick.

```
$timeout(function(){
    var returnString = '';
    for(i=0; i<compiledHTML.length; i++)
        returnString += compiledHTML[i].outerHTML;

    console.log(returnString);
},0);
```