# AngularJS get 'compiled html'

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Say I have the following anglarjs DOM Structure

```
<div ng-init="isRed = true" 
    ng-class="{'red': isRed == true, 'black': isRed == false}">

    ... content

</div>
```

How would I get the 'compiled' version of this on a click event for example? I.e.

```
<div class="red">
     ... content
</div>
```

I've got an angularjs page that uses various ui-bootstrap components and I want to get the raw html of the page, send it to a server so that it (server) can generate a .pdf file from the sent html.

The server will have access to all relevant css files.

Edit:

I have tried innerHTML to no avail.

Comment: I think this is unrelated to your question, but is the ">" at the end of the first line part of your actual code or just a typo in this question?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo - edited.

Comment: $sanitize service might be what you're looking for:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598464/getting-compiled-html-from-angularjs) for a solution.

Comment: @dr I have tried the timeout method, I believe our scenarios are different

Comment: "I want to get the raw html of the page" > When ? On what specific event ? (Dom ready ? button click ? )

Comment: Btn click, sorry should have added that one in :)

Comment: Timeout method works in your case too, have a [look](http://plnkr.co/edit/sItgD48jeaTirm4VZWXF?p=preview). Just don't do it in a directive but keep a reference to your element and do it on a button click.

Comment: I now have this working, I will come back to this shortly and up-vote / accept where appropriate. Cheers all!

Answer (score 1):

You could try brute-force:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

For example:

```js
function showHTML() {
  window.alert(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input type="text" ng-model="tester" ng-class="{'red': tester==='red'}">
  <p>The inputted value is ***{{tester}}***</p>
</div>
<button onclick="showHTML()">Show HTML</button>
```

Run the code, fill in the text box and look for the `***`s in the alert box. Above them, if you entered `red` in the input box, you'll see class="... red".

Comment: I was trying to perform a callback, but depending on its utilisation, this could do the job perfectly.

Comment: I don't think this would give the desired output, i.e. having 'class="red"' output where the condition on ng-class is true for it to have the 'red' class?

Comment: It doesn't change ng-class, but it gives the class (class="red" is included among the actual classes)

Comment: On my Chrome, the class="red" is not rendered actually.

Comment: @enguerranws not rendered visually or in the alert box? (it can't be rendered visually, didn't add any CSS :-D). Tested it in Chrome actually, but it should work everywhere that has getElementsByTagName as the changes angular makes to the DOM have to appear in the DOM, thus also in innerHTML

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for `input` elements; it doesn't show the values.

Answer (score 0):

Angular compiles you views according to controller values for bindings but it does not remove the ng-class like directives from your html, because it still watches and applies the scope changes into your view. for example it compiles `ng-class="{'red': true}"` into `class="red"`, but ng-class part still remains

Comment: Yes that doesn't matter to me, I've given my use case. I want the html output to contain 'class="red"', whether or not it contains the ng-class directive doesn't matter

Comment: try getElementBySelector("whatever") and cloneNode. you should be able to get the compiled version in the dom

Answer (score 0):

**Souldreamer's answer is right, as long as you wrap it into Angular's $scope :**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) { 
 $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.click =function(){
     alert(document.getElementById('my-el').innerHTML); // class="red", and template rendered
    };


}
```

Live demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21029/